# don't work datapicker in my project

Tags: jquery, node.js, datepicker

I'm trying to simulate a SPA application, injecting content into the central block of my page, not to load entire pages on my web. But when I use a datepicker in one of my injections the calendar is not displayed.

I go loading the central content according to the sections of my page that are selected, I upload them to the general.js file, using JQuery.load charge the html and js asociate to the new section of my page.

In index.jade I have the first page (the only one that is loaded) in node.js:

```
doctype html
  html
   head
meta(http-equiv="Content-Type", content="text/html; charset=utf-8")
meta(http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible", content="IE=edge")
title Planet
base(href='/')
meta(name='viewport', content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
link(rel='icon', type='image/x-icon', href='favicon.ico')
//link(id="template-file", href="views/modals.html", rel="import") 
link(href="AdminLTE-2.3.11/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css", type="text/css", rel="stylesheet")
link(href="AdminLTE-2.3.11/dist/css/skins/_all-skins.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
link(href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css', rel='stylesheet')
link(href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
link(href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css", rel="stylesheet")
script(type='text/javascript', src='https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js')
script(type="text/javascript", src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/js/bootstrap-datepicker.min.js")
link(rel="stylesheet", href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-datepicker/1.4.1/css/bootstrap-datepicker3.css")
link(href='css/mis_estilos.css', rel='stylesheet')

script.
  $(document).ready(function(){
  var date_input=$('input[name="date"]'); //our date input has the name "date"
  var container=$('.bootstrap-iso form').length>0 ? $('.bootstrap-iso form').parent() : "body";
  var options={
  format: 'mm/dd/yyyy',
  container: container,
  todayHighlight: true,
  autoclose: true,
  };
  date_input.datepicker(options);
  })

body

.container
  .row
    include ./../public/views/header.html
  br
  br

  .row#bloque_central
    .row#contenido_central


 include ./../public/views/footer.html
```

footer.html :

```
<div id="scripts_footer"></div>
 <script 
  src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js">
 </script>
 <script src="../AdminLTE-2.3.11/dist/js/app.min.js"></script>
 <script src="js/general.js"></script>
```

my new page inyection:

```
<div class="bootstrap-iso">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">

<!-- Form code begins -->
<form method="post">
  <div class="form-group"> <!-- Date input -->
    <label class="control-label" for="date">Date</label>
    <input class="form-control" id="date" name="date" placeholder="MM/DD/YYY" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group"> <!-- Submit button -->
    <button class="btn btn-primary " name="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
 </form>
 <!-- Form code ends --> 

</div>
</div>    
</div>
</div>
```

I have already tried several things like initialize the datepicker in the js of the new section, but it still does not show up

Comment: Are you sure your jade/pug indentation is well written?

Comment: _“I have already tried several things like initialize the datepicker in the js of the new section, but it still does not show up”_ - script elements in content loaded into the document via AJAX are not executed by default; suggest you go read up on how that is achieved.

Comment: Of course, I guess what is happening is that my dynamic content that I injected with .JQuery, load is not taken into account by jquery to apply the datepicker, but there has to be some way to make it apply the javascript to the datepicker, not ?
 Note: the indentation of my jade is another, but here I had to tabulate it like this.

Comment: it seems like maybe you are including the bootstrap-datepicker JS before the main bootstrap JS? The main bootstrap appears to be in your footer, while the datepicker is in the head area. It's not clear, but I assume the footer bit is rendered last to the page? I would suggest you make sure that bootstrap is loaded before any other items which depend on it. Do you get any browser console errors or warnings which would help us make a diagnosis?

Comment: I have solved the problem, the solution has been to initialize the datepicker when the new section of the html page is fully loaded, thanks to everyone :)